# Is it legal for a supermarket to refuse to sell an adult beer if an adult with them doesn’t have their ID?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, alcohol, is-x-legal, identification

Today I went with my dad grocery shopping at a supermarket in New York (ShopRite) and he put a six-pack of beer in the cart.

They then wouldn’t let him buy the beer because they couldn’t ID me (21, but I dress for work so I look more like 25). Even when I left the store to wait in the car they made him check out at a different register.

Is this legal? I wasn’t buying anything; I was just helping him load stuff onto the conveyor belt.

Comment: In the UK if you look under 25 (the legal drinking age is 18) you are required to prove your age and it is clearly written in large signs inside the shops. I was ID'd when aged 35.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to law.SE! Your question contained some details that are not relevant (such as why you do not like to carry a wallet). I edited these out to make the question more focussed and suitable for the site. Also, I added a tag to indicate this is in the US, since legal questions depend on jurisdiction. Feel free to re-edit if there is something wrong!

Comment: I've encountered a similar scenario with alcohol-free beer. Flat out refusal to trade in the presence of an actual minor.

Comment: My wife and I (both in our early thirties) have to present our IDs to the cashier whenever we buy alcohol together, regardless of store. We live in Upstate NY. The lost sale of a 6-pack is peanuts compared to losing a liquor license. Sometimes one of us forgets our wallet in the car so the other will simply check-out alone.

Comment: From the store's perspective, you're not an adult, you're a possible minor.

Comment: I'm surprised they let your dad buy the beer at all. Walmart wouldn't have. Once you get to the register with someone who isn't obviously over 28, without an ID to prove they're over 21, they wouldn't sell to the other person.

Comment: @VladimirF The US takes this to its logical conclusion though - not just how old you look, but requiring you to actually prove your age regardless.  When I was working in Michigan, I saw a man get carded in TGI Friday's.  If you took Iggy Pop's body, put Dusty Hill's head and beard on top of it, and made him a whole lot more salt-and-pepper, you'd be about there.  He was there with his family, who themselves can't have been less than mid-40s.  And he got asked for ID when he ordered a drink.

Comment: This is weird and happens in Texas too. Parents can buy wine when their 5 year old is in tow, can legally let their kids drink at home with them, can LEGALLY let restaurants serve alcohol to their underage kids when the parent is with them in the restaurant! but if their kids look over 10 they can't sell the parent alcohol at a store unless they leave their kids out in the hot car. Lawmakers are nuts now.

Comment: @VladimirF This question is not about the purchaser's age or ID / lack of ID. It is about the lack of ID of someone *accompanying* the purchaser. Nothing about that scenario is clearly written on shop signs.

Comment: @Graham I too witnessed an ID check with an obvious octogenarian. Come to think of it, it is way more likely for a Joe avareage waiter to misread the date of birh  on an ID or err in the current year or miscalculate the age from those two dates or misidentify the person with the photo on the ID than to misjudge a minor for an octogenarian on direct view.

Comment: So a simple way to annoy other customers who want to buy alcohol (and if you are or look young) is to just stand by them while they apporach the register. ..?

Comment: In Ontario if an obvious adult is  in a liquor store with someone who looks underage and the latter person physically touches the booze they'll refuse to check out the obvious adult unless they can ID the younger looking person with them as being of age (19 yo in this case) <shrug>.

Comment: Surely a company is under no legal obligation to sell a particular product to any particular person.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It is legal, at least in the US, for a store (or other entity) to refuse to sell any item to any individual for any non-prohibited reason (prohibited reasons are typically things like race or religion).

More over, in various US jurisdictions, it is prohibited to "furnish" alcohol to a "minor" (for example, under California's ABC law), which can be interpreted as prohibiting to an adult if they reasonably suspect that adult will pass the alcohol onto the "minor". This is to prevent "straw" sales.

Additionally, larger chains generally prefer to have harmonized policies across branches, and where practical, across state lines, so will have policies that can accomodate multiple alcohol control regimes.

Comment: That seems a little weird but I guess that’s how stores can turn away rude customers if they want. Thanks for explaining. Edit: wait a sec what about that whole “I won’t sell my cakes to gay people” debacle? I know that’s a totally different stone (and quite a controversial one) but if stores can just refuse whoever then that shouldn’t have been a problem? Or was it profiling because they specified why they were refusing them?

Comment: See above: Any "non-prohibited" reason. If there is a prohibition against  discrimination in sexual orientation (which I believe Washington State had at the time), then it would be illegal to refuse to sell for that reason. The legal rationale that led to the appeals up to the Supreme Court, as I recall, had to do with whether the wedding cake (which apparently are always made-to-order) transaction was a sale(where discrimination would be illegal), or a contract (where it would be legal). But I may be wrong about that last bit.

Comment: It's not just a "can be interpreted". Some jurisdictions specifically include it as a reason to deny sales; others recommend or even require age ID for all persons who look less than a certain age (which is often much higher than the legal minimum); and others still apply these requirements to all persons in a party where any attempt to purchase alcohol (i.e. everybody has to pass together or nobody can).

Comment: @Nij So if I follow this policy I can't buy beer or wine when I'm going grocery shopping with my young children ? I understand the legality behind it (basically stores do as they please as long as there's no discrimination), but isn't there an exception to this policy when the group is a family and not a bunch of college students ?

Comment: You'd have to look at the policy or law itself that you're asking about. There are thousands of jurisdictions and millions of companies selling alcohol in the world, and they're not all the same.

Comment: _"It is legal for a store to refuse to sell any item to any individual for any non-prohibited reason (prohibited reasons are typically things like race or religion)."_ Age (over 40) is also a protected class, at least in employment.

Comment: @orlp - this may be the case, but aside from whether age is a protected class in non-employment legislation, the product in question is age-controlled, so the store's defence could be that they are attempting to comply with the legislation. This would be especially the case if the law includes something like sharur mentions in the second paragraph.

Comment: @LouisaCarlson you should read the full story of that debacle, it wasn't as clear cut as that one liner.

Comment: @zakinster From my own experience working at a liquor store.  If you brought true kids into the store we would usually sell to customers still, however, if they came in with college age kids we did refuse them.  Usually around graduation times and when we had to worry about police stings.

The worry was over teens asking a passing adult to 'be their dad for 5 minutes' for exactly the purpose of getting alcohol underage

Comment: @orlp That is irrelevant. The cashier is not refusing the sale because of the purchaser being over 40.

Comment: @CaptainMan I'm not saying that particular ruling is relevant to the issue at hand, I just find it weird that the OP mentioned various protected classes but didn't touch upon the fact that 'age' is *sometimes* a protected class, but not here.

Comment: @orlp age technically *IS* a protected class, even here -- but they're not refusing to sell the product because of the purchaser's age, they're refusing to sell it because the transaction is potentially illegal (which in this case *happens* to be due to a member of the party appearing possibly underage).

Comment: Sounds like discrimination against people not clever enough to figure out their straw buyer shouldn't be accompanied by thirsty teens. i.e. It seems to me like a case of over-zealous policy that punishes/annoys innocent non-straw sales like the OP's dad, but only prohibits incompetent attempts at straw sales.

Comment: @Dronz It probably also has an effect on peoples' mindsets. Without that rule people will be thinking "Yeah it's easy to get beer if you're under 18, the stupid law just says someone over 18 has to come with you so it's technically them buying it"

Comment: Side note: it is far safer (from customer satisfaction point of view) for the store to uniformly check ID than occasionally say/imply "you look 40ish, no need for ID" … which may sound fine if customer is 50+... but try it on  25+ :)

Comment: @Dronz Well, cleverness or lack thereof isn't a protected class. You can't expect a store to know all and see all, but you can expect them to try and at least make an effort to comply with laws. (Since otherwise, there's a chance they could be seen as negligent and face fines)

Comment: "pass" as in "let the minor touch the alcohol bottle" (by putting it in a grocery bag for instance) or as in "buy it for him and give it to him so that he can drinks it"? I am asking because I heard (20+ years ago so things may have changed) that a minor **cashier** was not even allowed to process alcoholic beverages in the US.

Comment: @Dronz it is amazing how much you can decrease a behavior by making it mildly inconvenient.

Answer (score 48):

You go into a store, pick up an item, go to the counter and you think you are legally entitled to own the item provided that you pay for it? Wrong. Wrong for *any* item, not just alcohol.

Items that are on the shelves in stores are not *offers* in terms of contract law. They are [invitations to treat/bargain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_treat). When you take an item to the counter it is you who makes an offer to pay for it. And the store is free to accept or reject your offer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99260/discussion-on-answer-by-greendrake-is-it-legal-for-a-supermarket-to-refuse-to-se).

Answer (score 23):

The answers here are already correct, but wanted to make a quick comment over this

> Even when I left the store to wait in the car they made him check out at a different register.

It is of course completely silly that this is required, but from what I was told when I worked at a liquor store this was needed.  The idea is by checking out at a different register with a different cashier it passes liability over to the customer if anything bad was happening.  The original cashier already knows that Person A came in with Person B who could not be properly ID'd, so even if Person B leaves, OG Cashier is obligated to refuse sales to Person A.  Switching over to a new lane meant Person A was now in a 'new' interaction with New Cashier who has no knowledge of Person B and would not be knowingly making 'straw sales' as @sharur mentioned.

Things always got interesting when the adult got annoyed with their 'kid' for wasting more of their time and said they are charging them more.  And then they got really confused when we refused any further sales at all....

Comment: This does *not* shift liability in any way. If the cashier knows Person A could not produce ID and are aware Person B is still in the store, they are obligated to inform their colleague of the matter and still refuse sale. Liability only disappears if the other cashier had no knowledge of the previous interaction and the previous cashier was unable to inform them. To explicitly tell them to try a different register is a blatant violation of ID protocols.

Comment: @animuson If you'd like to get that technical, then it does shift some liability over to OG Cashier as an accomplice to a crime being committed by Person A.  The store's liquor license will still be at risk, but depending on prior infractions it may not be revoked immediately and they could discipline (probably fire) the employee and make a case for keeping it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just legal, but often (depending on the state/county) *legally required*, otherwise they would be considered 'negligent' in helping providing a minor with alcohol, which can get them in jail.

Comment: So families in the USA buying groceries with the entire family cannot buy alcohol or tobacco if accompanied by their children?

Comment: @gerrit Depending on the state, yes that's right. Some states have extremely restrictive regulations regarding alcohol. Remember, this is a country that edited its _Constitution_ to make the production, sale and consumption of alcohol illegal. And then changed it back again...

Comment: @gerrit At least one state went further (Maryland) and decided to just ban grocery stores from selling alcohol at all. Dad or Mom has to go next door to the liquor store.

Comment: @pboss3010 I don't agree that banning grocery stores from selling (strong) alcohol (which exists in Sweden, Norway, Finland, Iceland, among other places) goes further than banning minors from accompanying adults when adults buy alcohol.  Unless you're saying that minors are prohibited from even entering those liquor stores, such that a lone parent with a toddler cannot buy alcohol there. Do those liquor stores have to check the ID of everybody who enters and leaves the shop, or only of those who buy anything?

Comment: @gerrit If it helps, this craziness wasn't caused by the scenarios here.  Overly strict politicians got upset that 21-25 yr olds were buying alcohol that the 16-20 yr olds would hand select at a store and immediately start consuming once the 'adult' had purchased it.  

So yes, when I saw 4 kids walk in and select a variety of alcohol when I worked at a liquor store I would need to card all 4 of them.  Usually 2 of them would leave while the other 2 purchased and then lied saying they had no idea who those others were.  We would ask for their IDs anyways and end up refusing the entire sale

Comment: There normally is an exemption for children with a parent.